Apex: Ternary operator and SonarQube warning
I have the following Boolean assignemnt:
Contact currentContact = new Contact();

currentContact.Is_Manager__c = UserWrapper.isManager() != null ? UserWrapper.isManager() : false;

UserWrapper class has isManager() method that can return either True, False or Null.
CurrentContact.Is_Manager__c should either be true or false, not null.
I'm getting "Remove the unnecessary Boolean literal" warning in Sonarqube due to the 'false' in the ternary operator. Is this expected?

Does this answer your question? Remove unused Boolean literal

I think you meant UserWrapper.isManager() in both instances, rather than User.isManager(). Maybe that's causing the confusing error?
That said, there's a more modern way to write your code, assuming SonarQube supports it:
currentContact.Is_Manager__c = UserWrapper.isManager() ?? false;

The new null coalescing operator greatly improves code readability.
In any case, if the code was just a typo (we all do that from time to time), consider submitting a bug to SonarQube regarding the behavior.

You’re right, I meant UserWrapper in both instances. In the code that is ok though, the typo happened when writing the question here. It’s great to know about the new coalescing operator but I think the sonar warning will remain the same, since the Boolean literal “false” it’s still there.

@Teo If so, I would also expect you to get a SonarQube warning: "null" should not be returned from a "Boolean" method on the isManager function. If so, then the ternary/null coalesce is actually redundant. Otherwise, it's a bug in the rule engine to report this as redundant yet not report isManager for misbehaving.
